# HPE ProLiant DL380e Gen8 - ILO seems OK but server does not power up

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo, hpe

I have an **HPE ProLiant DL380e Gen8** rack server.

I can't make the server power up. It stays "silent".

The ILO 4 web interface works fine and it shows status:

- System Health: [tick] OK
- iLO Health: [tick] OK
- Server Power: OFF

I don't see any problems in the iLO overview or log.

The front system power LED is amber (static, not blinking).

The system is equipped with redundant PSUs of the same type.

What I tried:

- Replaced both PSUs with spare parts. But it didn't help.
- In iLO, I go to "Power Management" -> "Server Power" -> "Power On: [Momentary Press]" and press the "virtual power button". But nothing happens.
- I removed the BIOS battery for a few minutes. -> Did not help.
- I enabled switch 6 of the system maintenance switch. -> Did not help.

Do you have any ideas? Can I run some more diagnostics?

Comment: did it ever work? Ive seen mixing things like the raid controler from seemingly identicle boards cause this

Comment: Have you powered off the system completely (disconnected both power cords simultaneously for at least 10 seconds)?